¿Cómo Autocompletar un combobox con valores que contengan una cadena?
Necesito que en la lista autocompletada de un combobox aparezcan los valores que CONTENGAN la cadadena digitada y no los que comiencien con dicha cadena.
Estoy usando un formulario en una Aplicación Escritorio con VS 2022 y C#.
¿Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?
Gracias
Tengo un combobox configurado de la siguiente manera:
CmbColor.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;           
CmbColor.AutoCompleteSource=AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
CmbColor.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutocompletarColores();

y mi método es:
public AutoCompleteStringCollection AutocompletarColores()
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection 
    autoCompleteStringCollectionColores = new 
    AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in listaColoresUnicos)
            autoCompleteStringCollectionColores.Add(item.Color);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Advertencia", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return autoCompleteStringCollectionColores;
}

El tema es que se autocompleta comenzado con la primera letra o cadena  digitada en el combo.
Y lo que necesito es que se autcomplete con los valores que contengan la cadena digitada.

Y todo depende de como se autocomplete el combobox y en que tecnologia estes trabajando.. no es lo mismo wpf que winforms que uwp que maui... y no es lo mismo segun el control que uses y tu control...

Hola. Estoy usando un formulario en una Aplicación Escritorio con VS 2022 y C#

Hay por lo menos 4 tecnologias para hacer apps de escritorio en .net.. cual de ellas usas?? y que componente?? y como haces el autocompletado???

bueno.. seguimos sin saber que tipo de app estas haciendo, pero ahora por lo menos por el codigo y las propiedades de los controles parecen ser winforms (y es muy importante que entiendas que hay mucha diferencia en el framework de visualizacion que usas). En fin, que yo sepa no hay forma de hacer lo que vos queres automaticamente.. capaz alguien sabe si se puede...

Hubieras comenzado por ahi....

Me parece que con el AutoComplete "default" no es posible ni para un TextBox ni para un ComboBox.
Yo lo haría "manualmente", variando la lista del DataSource cada vez que se escribe, para eso usaría el evento TextUpdate
Algo como esto:
Dejo explicación en los comentarios
private readonly List<string> list = ["casa", "auto", "atuo", "tomate", "vaca"];
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    comboBox1.TextUpdate += ShowSugerencias;
}
public void ShowSugerencias(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox? combo = sender as ComboBox;
    if (combo is null) return;

    var texto = combo.Text; //guardo el texto ingresado, porque al cambiar el DataSource se limpia
    combo.BeginUpdate();
    combo.TextChanged -= ShowSugerencias; //quito el evento, porque al cambiar el texto entraría en un loop infinito
    combo.DataSource = list.Where(x => x.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Contains(texto, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList(); // retorno una sublista a partir de la lista original con las palabras que "contienen". Además ignorando mayúsculas/minúsculas y tildes.
    combo.DroppedDown = true; // Expando el combobox, esto debe ir antes de volver a setear el texto
    combo.SelectedIndex = -1; // NO selecciono elementos
    combo.Text = texto; //vuelvo a agregar el texto que se está escribiendo (porque se limpió al cambiar el datasourse)
    combo.Select(texto.Length, 0); // El cursor del texto (el caret) se posicional al final
            
    combo.EndUpdate();
            
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default; //por una extraña razón el cursor del mouse desaparece, así que lo colocamos a la fuerza
    combo.TextUpdate += ShowSugerencias; //volver a agregar el evento

}

